# Чат-бот на telebot

Tags: python, telebot

У меня проблема у чат-бота на Python для Telegram. Вот принцип работы: Пользователь пишет запрос боту, бот отправляет сообщение мне, я пишу на него ответ, а бот отвечает пользователю мой ответ. В моём коде проблема, что когда бот отправляет мне сообщение пользователя и я на него отвечаю, он думает, что я задаю ему вопрос и отправляет мне мой же ответ на запрос пользователя в качестве вопроса от другого пользователя. Такая функция есть, но она не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста!

```
import telebot

# Создание экземпляра бота с токеном
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')
# Id в telegram
telegram_id = "1113086070"
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    if message.from_user.id != telegram_id:
        bot.send_message(telegram_id, message.text, disable_notification=message.from_user.id == telegram_id)
    else:
        reply_to_user(message)
# Отправка сообщения, полученного от пользователя, автору бота
bot.send_message(telegram_id, message.text, disable_notification=(message.from_user.id == telegram_id))
# Обработчик ответов на сообщения от бота
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.from_user.id == telegram_id)
def reply_to_user(message):
    # Отправка ответа бота пользователю
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text, disable_notification=True)

# Запуск бота
bot.polling()
```